# Static site generator that does not need node to compile

Tags: static-site

**Issue:** I know this may sound "silly" to some, but my need is very specific to *not using NODE*.

I'm looking for something I could modify and *design* easily without needing to dig into the deeper code. CSS, SASS, HTML, and that sort of thing are easy for me, but getting into NODE is a bit more beyond my current capabilities.

I'm more of a designer/artistic/UX rather than a coder.

**Goal:** I want to build a simple portfolio site that is easy to maintain, uses "templates" like Markdown, and doesn't require a database to keep track of things.

**Reasons:** Right now, I don't have *time* to learn Node. I've tried, and for me, the learning curve is a bit too steep. I need to take more time to really understand it. However, I need the site up and running, NOW, for job-hunting reasons.

I could just pull out notepad and do it all by hand, but I've seen the wonder of Static Site Generators. My hiccup is that almost all of the ones I've come across require Node - which means learning Node.

Comment: You don't need to learn node to use a tool written for node. It's only one command you'd ever need to use (and one for the installation of the tool).

Comment: While this seems pretty straight forward, my personal experiences with using things like Jekyll and Hugo have left me confused. I've tried Metalsmith and Wintersmith as well. I ended up trying Typesetter, which is a SSG CMS, and it's ok but lacks a lot of support and is doc-lite for sorting out problems.

Answer (score 0):

(You do know this is going to be closed as primarily opinion based, right? ️)

Anyways, you'll have to use some programming/templating language otherwise *it won't be a static site generator*. You only stated you don't want to use anything Node-based hence I'm going to list some popular non-Node-based static site generators:

- [Jekryll](https://jekyllrb.com/) seems very popular Ruby-based system sponsored by GitHub
- [Pelican](https://getpelican.com/) is Python-based and uses [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) for templating
- [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) is Go-based and uses [Go templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/) – apparently it also has [live updates](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo_server/) during development/design

Comment: (Heh. :) )
Maybe it's not "Node" but the compiler itself? Hrmm. I think I need to adjust my question?

But, anytime I go into the Command Line I have issues. Issues installing, issues with firewalls, issues with just getting it to freaking work at all. I follow the instructions and what's supposed to happen... doesn't. 

I don't know how, but I've BSOD'd my computer at one point.